# ng-book examples not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm currently reading through ng-book for angular js and have come accross two example pieces of code.

The first deals with the $parse service and can be found here: http://jsbin.com/UWuLALOf/1/edit

The second deals with $interpolate and can be found here: http://jsbin.com/oDeFuCAW/1/edit

Neither of these are working as expected (I think). They should be updating the view live. I've tried creating the first example locally but I get the same result. I thought maybe it was due to the version of angular but since it's using a specific version from the google api's this shouldn't be an issue. I'd like to figure out exactly what the parse and interpolate services are doing here so any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing newVal param to $parse function you should pass an expression **'expr'**

```
$scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
        var parseFun = $parse('expr');
        // Get the value of the parsed expression, set it on the scope for output
        scope.parsedExpr = parseFun(scope);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, bang on. Thanks a lot, was trying this for the entire day :-)

Answer (score 0):

that's beacues the version of angular which you attached to site is not stable version , use this

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
```

but nevertheless code are not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as expected but most likely you are not expecting what you should :)

Let's take one at a time:

```
  $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
      var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
      // Get the value of the parsed expression, set it on the scope for output
      scope.parsedExpr = parseFun(scope);
    }
  });
```

The $scope.$watch is setup and is monitoring changes tn the expr variable, which is tied with the input value via ng-model

If you change the expr value in the input, it is send to $parse for evaluation (1+1 should present 2, name should present {"name":"Ari Lerner"} in this case).
$parse will convert a string expression to a function, so having this in mind you should know what to expect.

In the second example, when the body part is changed via the textarea, the template is rendered via $interpolate which will evaluate anything inside {{ }} and then render the html.

Comment: sure $parse returns a function but that function is then executed in the next line. The way that the html is set up is a pretty clear indicator that parsedExpr should equate to newVal. The same can be said for the second example.

Comment: I can't get what your point is, is there something wrong in what i said above?

Comment: As I understand it, $parse evaluates an expresion as if we put it inside a double curly braces {{ }}. So we can evaluate "1 + 1" or call any property of the $scope?